# please let me know my Mistake

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct:

1- I am targeting to him or I am targeting him.

2- It appears fine to me or It appears fine me.

i request you to provide justification.

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 5):

> 1) I am **targeting** him.

Because *target* as used here is a transitive verb, it needs a direct object (him).

> 2) It **appears** fine to me.

Because *appear* as used here is an intransitive verb, you cannot have a direct object. So *me* is wrong and *to me* is correct.

I would recommend further study regarding the usage of transitive vs. intransitive verbs.